# Moving an item from Todolist to delete list and delete it from TodoList

Tags: reactjs

Hello i want to move an item from todo list to delete list in ReactJS and i want to delete it from todo list when i move it to done list i did everything i can delete the selected item or all items but i cant add it to done list when i move it

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todoinput from './Components/Todoinput'
import Todolist from './Components/Todolist'
import Tododone from './Tododone'
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import uuid from 'uuid';

class App extends React.Component {
  state= {
    items:[],
    id:uuid(),
    item:'',
    editItem:false
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState ({
      item:e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault ();
    const newItem = {
      id:this.state.id,
      title:this.state.item,
    };
    const updatedItems = [...this.state.items,newItem]
    this.setState ({
      items:updatedItems,
      item:'',
      id:uuid(),
      editItem:false
    })
  }
    clearList = (e) => {
      this.setState ({
        items:[]
      })
    }
  doneItem = (id) => {
    const doneItems = this.state.items.filter (item => item.id !== id);
      this.setState ({
        items:doneItems,
      }) 

    }
    handleEdit = (id) => {
      const doneItems = this.state.items.filter (item => item.id !== id);
      const selectedItem = this.state.items.find(item=> item.id === id)
      console.log(selectedItem)
      this.setState ({
        items:doneItems,
        item:selectedItem.title,
        editItem:true,
        id:id
      })
    }

  render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-8 mt-4">

              <h3 className="text-capitalize text-center">Todo Inputs</h3>
             <Todoinput item={this.state.item} handleChange={this.handleChange}
             handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
             editItem={this.state.editItem}
             />
                <Todolist items={this.state.items} clearList={this.clearList} doneItem={this.doneItem} handleEdit={this.handleEdit}/>
              <Tododone doneItem={this.doneItem} />

          </div>
            </div>
              </div>
      );
  }
}


export default App;

/**/


import React from 'react'
import Todoitem from './Todoitem'

class Todolist extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {items,clearList,doneItem,handleEdit}=this.props
        return (
            <ul className="list-group my-5">
                <h3 className="text-capitalize text-center">todo list</h3>

                {
                    items.map(item => {
                        return (
                        <Todoitem 
                        key={item} 
                        title={item.title}
                        doneItem={()=> doneItem(item.id)}
                        handleEdit={()=> handleEdit(item.id)}
                        />
                        )

                    })
                }
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-block text-capitalize mt-5"
                onClick={clearList}
                >clear list</button>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default Todolist

/**/

import React from 'react'

class Todoinput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {item,handleChange,handleSubmit,editItem} = this.props
        return (
            <div className="card card-body my-3">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <div className="input-group-prepend">
                            <div className="input-group-text bg-primary text-white">
                                <i className="fa fa-book" ></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control text-capitalize" placeholder="Add A To Do Item"
                        value={item}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" 

                    className={editItem ? "btn btn-block btn-success mt-3" : "btn btn-block btn-primary mt-3" }>
        {editItem ? 'Edit Item' : "Add Item"}</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todoinput
/**/

import React from 'react'

class Todoitem extends React.Component {

    render() {
  const {title,doneItem,handleEdit} = this.props
        return (
            <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-2">
                <h6>{title}</h6>
                    <div className="todo-icon">
                    <span className="mx-2 text-success" onClick={handleEdit}>
                        <i className="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span className="mx-2 text-danger"onClick={doneItem}>
                            <i className="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default Todoitem

/**/

import React from 'react'

class Tododone extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {items,clearList,doneItem,title,item}=this.props
        return (
            <div>
            <h2 className="text-capitalize text-center">Done Items</h2>
            <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-2">
                    <h6>{item}</h6>
                    <div className="todo-icon">
                        <span className="mx-2 text-danger" onClick={doneItem}>
                            <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-block text-capitalize mt-5"
                onClick={clearList}>clear list</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Tododone
```

so if anyone can help Please i post all the code above if anyone can help me please <

Comment: Please if u want to edit the code edit on my code dont change it so i can understand what happen i dont want the answer only iam doing this project for my self i just want to understand how u done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track if a task is done, add a `isDone` field to item, when you say it's done, flag it to `true`.
So when you create a new item:

```
const newItem = {
      id:this.state.id,
      title:this.state.item,
      isDone: false
};
```

When you render items that are **not done**, filter through `isDone===false`, like this:

```
<Todolist items={this.state.items.filter(item => item.isDone === false)} ... />
```

When you delete an item from the `ToDoList` you want it to go to the `DoneList`, so you set your `doneItem` function like this:

```
doneItem = id => {
    const newItems = [...this.state.items];
    const item = newItems.find(item => item.id === id);
    item.isDone = true;
    this.setState({
      items: newItems
    });
}
```

When you render the done list, filter through `isDone === true`, like this:

```
<Tododone items={this.state.items.filter(item => item.isDone === true)} ... />
```

Now get the `items` prop in `Tododone` and map it to see the done items, this below is just an example:

```
{items.map(item => (
   <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-2">
     <h6>{item.title}</h6>
     <div className="todo-icon">
       <span className="mx-2 text-danger" onClick={doneItem}>
         <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
       </span>
     </div>
   </li>
))}
```

Since I don't know what you want to do with those `div`s and `span`s I'll leave them like you set them.

When you click on clear list I assume you want to delete *only* the `todoList` or only the `doneList`, I suggest you to pass a flag to tell `App` which list to clear.

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/todolist-tishk) with *your* code that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

down and dirty because I have to head to work would be to add something like `doneItemsArray: []` in your state and then just do another filter in your doneItem method.

```
doneItem = id => {
  const filteredTodos = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  const doneItem = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id === id);
  this.setState({
    items: doneItems,
    doneItemsArray: [...this.state.doneItemsArray, doneItem]
  });
};
```

Comment: Okey fine now there's no error in App.js / now i need to add that thing to Tododone right